# Triggering another function in method lifetime in sequence diagram

Tags: sequence-diagram

I have a specific question about sequence diagram demonstration. I have a method that have flags that trigger other methods. I don't call other methods in this method, however the flag variables are affecting other methods. Should I include those methods that are notified in the lifetime of this method and how?

(I can not put my code it is too long and complex, if the question is not clear I can draw what I mean.)